# Map Channel Mutes to Keys or MIDI note toggle

Tags: logic-pro

I have some tracks I would like to simultaneously *play* the mute button on (dub-style), and either record as automation or route to audio tracks.

To be clear, I want to be able to turn the different tracks on and off (up and down in volume could work as well) independently of one another.

Not seeing an option to MIDI-learn on `mute` in the Channel Mixer, or a way to assign specific mixer channels to key commands.
Using Logic Pro X

Any recommendations?

Comment: this 3rd party site reckons this works for mute too - https://www.logicprohelp.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=432 - can't test, don't use Logic.

Answer (score 1):

This is an XY answer, giving you a solution to what you want to achieve, rather than answering the actual question about automating mutes. Let the downvotes commence…!

I would advise against using mute for this purpose as you might get clicks with these instant changes of volume. There a few better ways to do this:

- automate the volume with very short ramps up and down
- use an inverted noise gate (set as a “ducker”) side chained to another track that plays notes whenever you want the gaps in your other tracks. Something with a constant volume, like a simple synth, would work well for this. The advantage of this method is that you can subtly change the attack, release, threshold, hold etc. on the noise gate to get exactly the sound you want.

**Most importantly though**, whichever method you choose to use for this ducking, it is much easier to apply this to multiple tracks by first sending them all to one Aux track.

Comment: idk Logic very well, I'm Cubase, but you could probably do this on group channels too, rather than auxes. [btw, I've never known Cubase's mutes (or indeed any on/off switch) to click. I'd assumed they're 'softened' some way internally, otherwise people would constantly complain about them.]

Comment: First of all, thank you very much. Updated the question. I want to be able to change the volume or "on" state of each channel independently so that I can *play* the five channels like you would on a mixing board. I thought about doing it with a ducker, which I supposed could be done by sending different MIDI notes to different instruments, each which would be chained to a different gate, or maybe you can send a specific MIDI note to a certain instrument, or perhaps filter out all the other notes.

Comment: Ahhh - okay! I might redo the answer or do a different one. I’m in the pub at the moment so maybe not tonight…

Comment: Interesting concept BTW…

Comment: One thing that can be automated is the on/off for any plugin (bypass). Several plugins should be able to stop any signal going through (e.g. noise gate with a high dB). However, Logic tends to pop and click when you automate bypass on and off… I’ll have a think over another pint…